# How to use Grahql API with ACL resouce as Rest API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, permissions, graphql, user-roles

We have a issue and want to limit permission each roles.

Do we have any way to make Graphql can set permission roles as Rest API?

EX:
Admin token with roles "sales", they only access Graphql APIs of Sales.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find anything cleary documented regarding this, so here is what I used. Not sure if it's the best way so please let me know!

In resolver class or interface that handles the graphql request:

```
//add the dependency to your constructor
Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface

...

//use the authorization to check the resource id set in acl.xml
// throw exception (or you could return false or do something else)
if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('Your_Resource_Id')) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(__('Forbidden'), 0, 403);
}
```